# How to get an XML value from a .xml file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a file called 'status.xml' that contains the following:

```
<response>
<r1>~relay(1)~</r1>
<r2>~relay(2)~</r2>
<ct>~currentime~</ct>
<soc>~gaugeSOC~</soc>
<t1>25</t1>
</response>
```

From an .htm page located in the same root directory as my status.xml file, I want to fetch the value at  and have it parsed as an integer. I tried the following two methods unsuccessfully:

```
<script>
...
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("status.xml");
gaugeSOC.setValue(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('t1'));
</script>
```

OR

```
<script>
...
var x = getXMLValue('status.xml', 't1');
gaugeSOC.setValue(x);
</script>
```

Where gaugeSOC.setValue(int) receives an integer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Where do `loadXMLDoc` or `getXMLValue` come from? Can you use file paths with them or do you need to use URLs, i.e. `loadXMLDoc("http://yourdomain/subpath/status.xml")`

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('t1')
```

This line returns a list of node Objects and therefore can not be directly converted into an Integer value. You have to select the right sub-element first:

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('t1')
var i = x[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

That should do the job, for reference here is an example which shows roughly what you are trying to do: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_nodelist.asp